# Eclipse EMF Compare for XML files

Tags: eclipse, xsd, modeling, emf, ecore

I am trying to follow up this link: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Comparing_XML_files_with_EMF_Compare  in order to use EMF Compare for XML files.
It seems this is possible with Eclips by providing the XML schema (.xsd).

By following the sub-tutorial on http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/docs/2.x/tutorials/xlibmod/xlibmod_emf2.0.html, it seems I'm missing something as the part "Step 4: Run the Generated Editor" I do not have the option to run as Run-time Workbench.

Did anyone successfully compared XML files through EMF Compare? Is this tutorial outdated and not compatible with the following Eclipse version:

```
Eclipse Modeling Tools
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg-449, this worked. I was able to build my model now, trying to figure out on how to import the XML following the model. Could you please answer the question so that I can close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this Run option is now called 'Run As > Eclipse Application'.

The tutorial is 15 years old and based on Eclipse 3.0 which is 19 releases out of date so some things are likely to have changed.